# How do I pick up the shrine orb in Kakariko Village?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Next to Impa there is an orange orb like you find at shrines. On one of the hills above Kakariko Village, there is a pedestal with a slot for an orb. If I try to pick up the orb, Impa tells me off.

How do I pick up the orb?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to complete all of the other side quests in Kakariko Village first, then you will unlock a new sidequest that will let you use the orb.

You need to complete these sidequests first:

- Flown The Coop
- Arrows of Burning Heat
- By Firefly's Light
- Find the Fairy Fountain

Note that you can only use the orb in Kakariko on the pedestal. If you try to use another one, it will not work:

[image]
*(Image source: 4chan)*

Comment: I'm unsure if the sidequests you get from children in kakariko count towards this requirement (the three cooking ones and the hide and seek one) -- if anyone knows for sure, go ahead and edit this answer

Comment: The sidequests that matter are detailed in a book found inside Impa's house.

Comment: Dumb question: how do I activate the firefly side quest?  I can talk to the shop girl, but the quest doesn't activate.  Oh, I guess you need to do the side quests in a certain order? Find the fairy fountain before by firefly's light?

Comment: @JAL You start the firefly side quest by talking to the shop girl in the evenings while she's sitting in her home.